# High-speed vs High Rate

Tags: wan

Is There any difference between them? For example, about ISDN

"To suporte application requiring high-speed voice, video, and data communication"

"When you need both a consistent and very high rate of data speed and transfer"

both sounds like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data bits flow at exactly the same speed down the wire (the speed of light in the medium of travel).  So a bit of data travelling 1000 miles down a 10 meg circuit arrives at the other end at exactly the same time as a bit travelling down a 100Gig connection.  The difference is the RATE at which the signal can transition state between 1 and 0.  The faster you can transition the state of the signal, the faster you can send the next bit.  So -- basically there is no such thing as "speed" because it all operates at the same speed (the speed of light), what differs is the RATE of data bits you can send.  That is the "bandwidth".

The faster I am able to flip the state of the signal from 1 to 0 and back again, the more data I can send in a given amount of time.  Imagine two signalmen using old time semaphore flags.  One signals quickly, one signals slowly.  The actual light reaching your eye is arriving at the same speed in both cases but one can send a lot more data in a given time than the other.  That signalman has more bandwidth and can send more data in a given period of time.  The data doesn't travel faster, but that one can pack more data into a given slice of time.

Comment: Good answer. I think what confuses people is that a higher bit-rate allows bytes (translate to packets, etc.) to get from one end to the other faster than a slower bit-rate. Many people equate that to a faster speed. The individual bits all travel at the same speed, but the bytes arrive faster.

Comment: So everytime that I read or listen "high-speed", means bandwidth? Doesn't matter speed, all travellin in the same time, downstream/upstream!

Comment: Correct.  What matters is the rate at which it can flip state to signal a binary 1 or a 0.  We are reaching the limit of what we can do over copper cable.  We *might* be able to get 25Gig (what comes next after 10Gig) over copper for short distances but I doubt we will get much more than that.  We are also reaching the limit of what we can do for any significant distance over multimode fiber. If I were planning a new data center, I'd use single mode fiber these days.

Comment: Do you have more texts about it? about that flip state to signal

Answer (score 0):

Not in the context of ISDN links.  In terms of networking device throughput there is a differentiation of packets-per-second and switching capacity (Gbps).

The reason why we need pps is that switch/router's packet processing capability depends on packet size. That is, switch/router can't do wire speed for all packets size, but should be able to process most packet sizes at line rate.

Comment: What the difference between wire speed (FastEthernet 100 Mbit's) and BandWidth? When I started to study CCNA always see it, but I never searched!

Comment: Wire speed refers to a networking devices ability to pass traffic without delay at the speed of the interfaces.  Bandwidth refers to capacity of a link between endpoints.  So, bandwidth is denoted in Mbps and wire speed is relevant to the ingress and egress ports on a networking device.